# jquery ui sortable list not tracking updates to attributes of list items

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm working with a list whose items are both selectable (using checkboxes) and sortable (using jquery 'sortable').

The list looks like this:

```
<ul id="dragdrop">
    <li id="1290"><input type="checkbox" id="290" checked class="slideToggle" /><img ... /></li>
    <li id="1291"><input type="checkbox" id="291" checked class="slideToggle" /><img ... /></li>
</ul>
```

...and the javascript looks like this:

```
$(".slideToggle").click(function () {
    var slideId = $(this).attr("id");
    var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
    if (slideId) { 
        $.post("ToggleInclusion", { "slideId": slideId, "isChecked": checked },
            function () {
                var newId = checked ? "1" : "0" + slideId;
                $(this).parent().attr("id", newId);
            });
    }
});

$("#dragdrop").sortable({
    update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("toArray").toString();
        $.post("UpdateOrder", { "order": order }, function () { });
    }
});
```

So when the user un-checks the checkbox for, say, the second item (id=291), its list item changes to

```
<li id="0291" ... ></li>
```

The problem that I'm running into is that this change is not captured by the sortable list. When the second item is unchecked and then dragged to a position before the first item, the order string that's posted to the server is "1291,1290" when it should be  "0291,1290".

I have tried calls to `$("#dragdrop").sortable("refresh")` and friends both at the end of the toggle callback and also just before the sortable update post, but no dice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to not bother with the sortable methods at all--just grab the desired properties directly from the check boxes:

```
$(".slideToggle").click(function () {
    var slideId = $(this).attr("id");
    var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
    if (slideId) { 
        $.post("ToggleInclusion", { "slideId": slideId, "isChecked": checked },
            function () { });
    }
});

$("#dragdrop").sortable({
    update: function() {
        var order = $(".slideToggle").map(function() {
            return ($(this).attr("checked") ? "1" : "0" + $(this).attr("id");
        }).get().join(",");
        $.post("UpdateOrder", { "order": order }, function () { });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "update" event, try "stop" instead and concatenate your own sort var.

```
$("#dragdrop").sortable({
  stop: function() {
    var order = "";
    $("#dragdrop").find("tr").each(function() {
        order = order + $(this).attr("id") + ",";
    });
    if(order.length > 0) order = order.substr(0, order.length - 1); // remove the last comma
    $.post("UpdateOrder", { "order": order }, function () { });
  }
});
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't do it.  Neither the use of the stop event nor the manual concatenation catches the updated id attributes.  I'm really surprised that doing `$('#dragdrop li').each(...` doesn't pick up the correct id values.  I'm thinking there's something more fundamental that I'm missing, like maybe the fact that the attributes of the list items are cached only when the page loads and therefore are not update-able after that?   when I uncheck some boxes and refresh the page and _then_ re-order, the updated attributes are picked up just fine.